# How to change text of a TextView inside a dialog box on multiple button click ? using kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-alertdialog

let Think I have two buttons.
I need to open Dialog for button click.
When button 1 clicked some text appears and when button2 clicked something other text appears as dialog.

My code

```
btn1.setOnClickListener{ showCustomDialog() }
btn2.setOnClickListener{ showCustomDialog() }
```

```
private lateinit var alertDialog: AlertDialog
    fun showCustomDialog() {
        val inflater: LayoutInflater = this.getLayoutInflater()
        val dialogView: View = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_custom_view, null)

        val headerbtn = dialogView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.header)
        headerbtn.text = "Header Message"

        val dialogBuilder: AlertDialog.Builder = AlertDialog.Builder(context!!)
        dialogBuilder.setOnDismissListener(object : DialogInterface.OnDismissListener {
            override fun onDismiss(arg0: DialogInterface) {

            }
        })
        dialogBuilder.setView(dialogView)

        alertDialog = dialogBuilder.create();
        alertDialog.window!!.getAttributes().windowAnimations = R.style.PauseDialogAnimation
        alertDialog.show()
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Send the String to the Function then put it on TextView.

```
btn1.setOnClickListener{ showCustomDialog("This is Text 1") }
btn2.setOnClickListener{ showCustomDialog("This is Text 2") }
```

Function :

```
fun showCustomDialog(data: String) {
    val inflater: LayoutInflater = this.getLayoutInflater()
    val dialogView: View = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_custom_view, null)

    val headerbtn = dialogView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.header)
    headerbtn.text = data

    val dialogBuilder: AlertDialog.Builder = AlertDialog.Builder(context!!)
    dialogBuilder.setOnDismissListener(object : DialogInterface.OnDismissListener {
        override fun onDismiss(arg0: DialogInterface) {

        }
    })
    dialogBuilder.setView(dialogView)

    alertDialog = dialogBuilder.create();
    alertDialog.window!!.getAttributes().windowAnimations = R.style.PauseDialogAnimation
    alertDialog.show()
}
```

Comment: did you added proper code i think you forgot to put the parameter in showCustomDialog()

Comment: need few more help from you. I am not mentioned above my actual requirement for simplify the question . When I have two TextView ? how to do this ?

Comment: You have two different textview then you need provide two variable throught Parameter.

Comment: `showDialog("This is Text 1", "This is Text 1.2")` and then change function depend `fun showCustomDialog(data: String, data1: String)`

Comment: @P.Mohanta worked ?. if you have null secondary string then put ? which allows nullable.